# Rendering SVG as XML using Glass Mapper

Tags: media-library, glass-mapper

I was curious if anyone has a good solution for rendering SVGs using Glass mapper so that the result is XML embedded into the HTML instead of an  tag. I know that I can use Editable() with a customized GetImageFieldValue pipeline processor, but that negates the performance benefits of skipping the RenderField pipeline by calling RenderImage().

This is in Sitecore 10 with Glass Mapper 5.8.117